# How can from the sum of invested amount and deposit amount using Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to withdraw some amount from my investment using the line of code below the account balance is not updating after withdrawal.

```
investment.basic_investment_return -= investment.basic_withdraw_amount
```

**Model**

```
from django.db import models
```

```
class Investment(models.Model):
    basic_deposit_amount = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    basic_interest = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    basic_investment_return = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    basic_withdraw_amount = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    basic_balance = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    investment_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.basic_interest =  self.basic_deposit_amount * 365 * 0.02/2
        self.basic_investment_return = self.basic_deposit_amount + self.basic_interest
        super(Investment, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**Forms**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Investment
```

```
class BasicInvestmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Investment
        fields = ['basic_deposit_amount']


class BasicWithdrawalForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Investment
        fields = ['basic_withdraw_amount']
```

**Views**

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect, render
from django.db.models import Sum, F
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import BasicInvestmentForm, BasicWithdrawalForm,
from .models import Investment,


def create_investment_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        basic_investment_form = BasicInvestmentForm(request.POST)
    
        if basic_investment_form.is_valid():
            investment = basic_investment_form.save(commit=False)
            investment.basic_investment_return += investment.basic_deposit_amount
            print(investment.basic_investment_return)
            investment.is_active = True
            investment.save()
            messages.success(request, 'your basic investment of {} is successfull '.format(investment.basic_deposit_amount))
        else:
            messages.success(request, 'your investment is not successfull! Try again.')
    else:
        basic_investment_form = BasicInvestmentForm()
        
    context = {'basic_investment_form': basic_investment_form}
    return render(request, 'create-basic-investment.html', context)


def create_withdrawal_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        basic_withdraw_form = BasicWithdrawalForm(request.POST)
        if basic_withdraw_form.is_valid():
            investment = basic_withdraw_form.save(commit=False)
            investment.basic_investment_return -= investment.basic_withdraw_amount
            print(investment.basic_investment_return)
            investment.save()
            messages.success(request, 'your withdrawal of {} is successfull '.format(investment.basic_withdraw_amount))
        else:
             messages.success(request, 'your withdrawal of {} is unsuccessfull '.format(investment.basic_withdraw_amount))
    else:

        basic_withdraw_form = BasicWithdrawalForm()
    context = {'basic_withdraw_form': basic_withdraw_form}
    return render(request, 'create-basic-withdrawal.html', context)
```

I can see the value of

```
print(investment.basic_investment_return)
```

in console but I noticed the result is always the deducted value.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more context on what's not working? Is it throwing an error? Is it resulting to an incorrect value? Also, please provide the result for `print(investment.basic_investment_return)` in your `create_withdrawal_view` method

Comment: I have updated my question to include print(investment.basic_investment_return). Here is  what I mean, lets say 4-3 = 1 but my code always return 4-3 = -3. It assumes 0-3 = -3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Editing my answer since there are new information given below and the post has been updated:**

You're expecting `investment.basic_investment_return` to have the value equal to the computation in your **Investment** save method. This will not work because the save method will only execute in `investment.save()`, which means:

```py
# if the user passes 10 for basic_deposit_amount, the computation 
# below is actually 0 = 0 + 10
investment.basic_investment_return += investment.basic_deposit_amount
```

Adding print lines like so will verify this:

**models**

```py
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f"Model basic_deposit_amount: {self.basic_deposit_amount}")
        self.basic_interest =  self.basic_deposit_amount * 365 * 0.02/2
        print(f"Model basic_interest: {self.basic_interest}")
        self.basic_investment_return = self.basic_deposit_amount + self.basic_interest
        print(f"Model basic_investment_return: {self.basic_investment_return}")
        super(Investment, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**create_investment_view**

```py
print(f"Form basic_investment_return: {investment.basic_investment_return}")
investment.basic_investment_return += investment.basic_deposit_amount
print(f"Computed basic_investment_return: {investment.basic_investment_return}")
```

The terminal will display the following:

```
Form basic_investment_return: 0
Computed basic_investment_return: 10
Model basic_deposit_amount: 10
Model basic_interest: 36.5
Model basic_investment_return: 46.5
```

If you intend to use the computation in your save method for both `create_investment_view` and `create_withdrawal_view`, I suggest you move it outside the class like so:

**models**

```py
# outside Investment
def compute_basic_interest_and_return(basic_deposit_amount):
    basic_interest = basic_deposit_amount * 365 * 0.02/2
    basic_investment_return = basic_deposit_amount + basic_interest

    return (basic_interest, basic_investment_return)
```

**views**

```py
from .models import compute_basic_interest_and_return

def create_investment_view(request):
        ...
        (basic_interest, basic_investment_return) = compute_basic_interest_and_return(
                investment.basic_deposit_amount
        )

        investment.basic_interest = basic_interest
        investment.basic_investment_return = basic_investment_return
        investment.basic_investment_return += investment.basic_deposit_amount
        ...

def create_withdrawal_view(request):
        ...
        (basic_interest, basic_investment_return) = compute_basic_interest_and_return(
                investment.basic_deposit_amount
        )

        investment.basic_interest = basic_interest
        investment.basic_investment_return = basic_investment_return
        investment.basic_investment_return -= investment.basic_withdraw_amount
        ...
```

Above is just a sample but I hope you understood the point. Note that you will also need to pass a value for `basic_deposit_amount` in your `create_withdrawal_view`, so update your **BasicWithdrawalForm** fields.

Comment: Basic Investment Return is a computed field. Adding it to BasicWithdrawalForm generates an input area in basic withdraw form that will force the user to enter a value, which is what I am trying to prevent. doing so also throws unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'NoneType' and 'int'. Maybe I don'tunderstand your suggestion.

Comment: @ThaddeausIorbee I think I should've clarified this. If we're not expecting an input from the user for `basic_investment_return`, then where is the data based from? Are we updating an existing record with an existing value for `basic_investment_return`? If yes, then can you move the print above the computation and comment the result?

Comment: The data is expected to come from the save method.  self.basic_investment_return = self.basic_deposit_amount + self.basic_interest Have a look at the investment model. I noticed the data is not even been saved because when I print investment.basic_investment_return I get <bound method Investment.basic_interest of <Investment: None>> in the save method.

Comment: @ThaddeausIorbee I've set up an environment for testing in my local. Can you please update your post and include this save method with the `self.basic_investment_return = self.basic_deposit_amount + self.basic_interest` computation so that I can test it myself.

Comment: Question updated. Check it now.

Comment: self.basic_investment_return = self.basic_deposit_amount + self.basic_interest is actually coming through.

Comment: I will go with your approach. It make more sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

investment.basic_investment_return is always going to be zero to start with, because you never set it.

When you call

```
investment = basic_withdraw_form.save(commit=False)
```

you create an investment instance based on the form, which has a single field, 'basic_withdraw_amount'. 'basic_investment_return' isn't provided so it will therefore always be its default value, which is 0:

```
investment.basic_investment_return -= investment.basic_withdraw_amount 
print(investment.basic_investment_return) 
#is the same as 0 - basic_withdraw_amount 
#BUT ONLY at point of print()
```

In the save function, you essentially overwrite the value you print() by setting

```
self.basic_investment_return = self.basic_deposit_amount + self.basic_interest
```

Currently the value you set in the view (the printed value) isn't being recorded, it only exists in the instance 'investment' briefly until the save function overrides it, both in the instance and the version saved to the database.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by deleting the save method from the model class and Running all logic in my views.

```
@login_required
def create_investment_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        basic_investment_form = BasicInvestmentForm(request.POST)
    
        if basic_investment_form.is_valid():
            investment = basic_investment_form.save()
            investment.basic_interest =  investment.basic_deposit_amount * 365 * 0.02/2
            investment.basic_investment_return = investment.basic_deposit_amount + investment.basic_interest
            investment.basic_investment_return += investment.basic_deposit_amount
            investment.is_active = True
            investment.save()
            print(investment.basic_interest)
            print(investment.basic_investment_return)
            print(investment.basic_deposit_amount)
            messages.success(request, 'your basic investment of {} is successfull '.format(investment.basic_deposit_amount))
        else:
            messages.success(request, 'your investment is not successfull! Try again.')
    else:
        basic_investment_form = BasicInvestmentForm()
        
    context = {'basic_investment_form': basic_investment_form}
    return render(request, 'create-basic-investment.html', context)
```

```
@login_required
def create_withdrawal_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        basic_withdraw_form = BasicWithdrawalForm(request.POST)
        if basic_withdraw_form.is_valid():
            investment = basic_withdraw_form.save(commit=False)
            investment.basic_investment_return -= investment.basic_withdraw_amount
            print(investment.basic_investment_return)
            investment.save()
            messages.success(request, 'your withdrawal of {} is successfull '.format(investment.basic_withdraw_amount))
        else:
             messages.success(request, 'your withdrawal of {} is unsuccessfull '.format(investment.basic_withdraw_amount))
    else:

        basic_withdraw_form = BasicWithdrawalForm()
    context = {'basic_withdraw_form': basic_withdraw_form}
    return render(request, 'create-basic-withdrawal.html', context)
```