# Why is my save method not returning any value

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

When I do:

```
investment.basic_interest
```

I get 0. Why is it returning 0? I feel my save method is not properly written. Any idea where the problem is coming from?

`Models.py:`

```
class Investment(models.Model):
    basic_deposit_amount = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    basic_interest = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.basic_interest =  self.basic_deposit_amount * 365 * 0.02/2  #calculated field. 
        super(Investment, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

`views.py:`

```
def create_investment_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        basic_investment_form = BasicInvestmentForm(request.POST)
    
        if basic_investment_form.is_valid():
            investment = basic_investment_form.save(commit=False)
            investment.basic_investment_return += investment.basic_deposit_amount
            print(investment.basic_interest)
            print(investment.basic_investment_return)
            print(investment.basic_deposit_amount)
            investment.is_active = True
            investment.save()
            messages.success(request, 'your basic investment of {} is successfull '.format(investment.basic_deposit_amount))
        else:
            messages.success(request, 'your investment is not successfull! Try again.')
    else:
        basic_investment_form = BasicInvestmentForm()
        
    context = {'basic_investment_form': basic_investment_form}
    return render(request, 'create-basic-investment.html', context)
```

Comment: Can you add the code that accesses the field and receives `0` to your question? Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72761930/how-can-from-the-sum-of-invested-amount-and-deposit-amount-using-django/72762276?noredirect=1#comment128522596_72762276  Python v2.8.13

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on where you are checking the value of `investment.basic_interest` in your code. The piece of code you have is executed only when the instance is saved (after the save() method is called).

```
def test_view(request):
    investment = Investment()
    investment.basic_deposit_amount = 100

    print(investment.basic_interest) # Prints 0

    investment.save()

    print(investment.basic_interest) # Prints 365.0
```

Comment: I have updated my question with views included. Its only basic interest that returns 0. That's where my problem is. Please have a look at my view.

Comment: Awesome, Since you have commit=False on the form instance save too, the save method on the model was not being called.

Answer (score 2):

You need to return what `super()` method does. Add `return` to last line:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.basic_interest =  self.basic_deposit_amount * 365 * 0.02/2  #calculated field. 
    return super(Investment, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I returned the super method as suggested but its still returning 0 as basic_interest.